# Is there a way I can simplify this selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#article").on('click', 
    'a[href^="/C"], a[href^="/Java"], a[href^="/T"]', function (event) {
```

Can this be simplified to not repeat the "href" so many times. Can I use a different kind of regular expression?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option would be is to give the all the three anchor tags `a single class Name`..

```
$("#article").on('click', 'a.planguages', function (event) {
```

Or any other selector that is common for these three..

Otherwise you cannot remove the `href` as that looks unique to the anchor tags in context.

Comment: Using a class is the easiest and cleanest way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

At least make that one work

```
$("#article").on("click", 'a[href^="/C"]', 'a[href^="/Java"]', 'a[href^="/T"]', "function(event){}")
```